# Facebook InsightsPresets not found

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Example from facebook dev site:

```
`use FacebookAds\Object\AdCampaign;
use FacebookAds\Object\Values\InsightsPresets;`

`$campaign = new AdCampaign('<AD_CAMPAIGN_ID>');
$params = array(
  'date_preset' => InsightsPresets::LAST_7_DAYS,
);
$insights = $campaign->getInsights(null, $params);
print_r($insights);`
```

But     `use FacebookAds\Object\Values\InsightsPresets;` does not exist in 
    `"facebook/php-business-sdk": "^3.2"`.

So I've tried to use:

```
use FacebookAds\Object\Campaign;
use FacebookAds\Object\Values\InsightsResultDatePresetValues;`
`$campaign = new Campaign('AD_CAMPAIGN_ID');
$params = array(
  'date_preset' => InsightsResultDatePresetValues::LAST_90D,
);
$insights = $campaign->getInsights(null, $params);
print_r($insights);
```

But it gives an error:

> Argument 1 passed to FacebookAds\Object\Campaign::getInsights() must
>   be of the type array, null given,

So what and how I need to use instead 
    `use FacebookAds\Object\Values\InsightsPresets;`

I need to get Insights from Campaigns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first params should be an array of requested fields. If you pass an empty array the endpoint return standard/default metrics. As example:

```
$fields = array();

$params = array(
      'date_preset' => InsightsResultDatePresetValues::LAST_90D,
    );
    $insights = $campaign->getInsights($fields, $params);
    print_r($insights);
```

Or:

```
$fields = array('clicks','cpc','cpm');

$params = array(
      'date_preset' => InsightsResultDatePresetValues::LAST_90D,
    );
    $insights = $campaign->getInsights($fields, $params);
    print_r($insights);
```

More info about field metrics [here in the doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-campaign-group/insights/#Reading)